# How can I use DFS algorithm for an implicit graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, pseudocode, depth-first-search, implicit

I have to find out if there is a path between s and t in an implicit graph, i.e. a graph with an unknown number of vertices, defined only by a function `NEXT(v)` that returns the list of vertices adjacent to v. Vertices are identified with the natural numbers. With a normal representation of the graph (adjacency lists) i would use this kind of DFS algorithm (in pseudocode):

```
DFS(G: Graph, s: Natural, t: Natural) : Boolean

    for v = 0 to G.adj.length - 1 do
        G.marked[v] = WHITE
    VISIT(G, s)
    if (G.marked[t] = WHITE) then return FALSE
    else return TRUE


VISIT(G: Graph, v: Natural)

    G.marked[v]  = GREY
    for each w : G.adj[v]
        if (G.marked[w] = WHITE)
            VISIT(G, w)
    G.marked[v] = BLACK
```

With the implicit graph the function `NEXT(v)` substitutes the array `G.adj[v]`, given that both return the same thing. My problem is: how to color white at the beginning all vertices if I don't know their total number? And then, if I discover a vertice with a number greater than the `marked` capacity, I cannot mark it. If I use a list instead of an array then I cannot check `if (G.marked[w] = WHITE)` without a search in the list (that is a waste of time).

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue? If not, what remains unclear?

Comment: What about heaps? Can they be a valid alternative to hash?

Comment: Why would you use heaps, and with what priority?

Comment: I thought that heaps improve search time, but now I'm not that sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use hash two sets, one for grey nodes, one for black noes. If a node is in neither, it is white. Pseudocode:

```
grey_nodes = new hash_set()
black_nodes = new hash_set()

if !grey_nodes.contains(v) and !black_nodes.contains(v)
    // do white stuff
else if grey_nodes.contains(v)
    // do grey stuff
else
    // do black stuff
```

Now whenever you color a node grey, put it into `grey_nodes`, and when you color it black, take it out of `grey_nodes` and put it into `black_nodes`.

Here a better version with one fewer `contains()` calls:

```
grey_nodes = new hash_set()
black_nodes = new hash_set()

if grey_nodes.contains(v)
    // do grey stuff
else if black_nodes.contains(v)
    // do black stuff
else
    // do white stuff
```

Comment: I'm not so practical with hash. Can you explain better?

Comment: Could the downvoter let me know what's wrong with this answer?